# Word for "philosophical thoughts"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> What was worse: doubt or the uncomfortable
>   truth? I was delving into this/these boredom-triggered [...] when my phone rang.

I thought of *dilemma* but I think it's kind of a different thing. More like a problem.

What's a better alternative?

Comment: If you're looking for a 10-cent word, you could try _lucubrations_, which is defined (by Merriam-Webster) as "laborious or intensive study; _also_ **:** the product of such study — usu. used in pl."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the word *these* into *this*, then I'd recommend using *conundrum*.

> What was worse: doubt or the uncomfortable truth? I was deliving into this boredom-triggered conundrum when my phone rang.

Answer (score 1):

**musing** Meditative. Thoughtfully abstracted.
[Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/musing)

> What was worse: doubt or the uncomfortable truth? I was musing on this when my phone rang.